# How do I install de b2 command line with cmake

Tags: python, boost, cmake

I have a c++ code that use boost functions. I want to install boost and link against my binary. But the boost repository doesn't have a cmake file and I coudn't use this repository as submodule. I could install boost using cmake. But to intall it, I have the b2 command line. I know the b2 command line is a python package.

My question: is possible to download this python package using a cmake file?

**EDIT:**

I know how to install de boost now with b2 command. But, I want only install de filesystem library. The boost directory has many content that I won't need. I have this cmake file, BUt I don't know how to exacly edited to archive my goal. I see a post here in stackoverflow that I can do something like that:

```
b2 tools/bcp
```

`mkdir /tmp/interprocess`

```
bcp interprocess /tmp/interprocess
```

But I don't know how to make this command line in side of a cmake file

my cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

include(ExternalProject)

# Download boost from git

SET (BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/boost/src/boost/lib/filesystem/include/boost/)
SET (BOOST_URL https://github.com/google/re2.git)
SET (BOOST_BUILD ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/boost/src/boost)  
get_filename_component(BOOST_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libboost_filesystem.a ABSOLUTE)  
SET (BOOST_INCLUDES ${RE2_BUILD})

if ( UNIX )
    SET (BOOST_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${BOOST_BUILD}/libboost_filesystem.a)
endif ()

ExternalProject_Add(
boost
PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/boost
GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
UPDATE_COMMAND ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=filesystem
CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
BUILD_COMMAND ./b2 tools/bcp link=static install --prefix=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/
BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
INSTALL_COMMAND ""
CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR/include/boost
})

set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/boost)

set(Boost_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/ibboost_filesystem.a)
```

**EDIT**

Guys, I want to do this by using git submodules.
I want use boost using submodules. But boost has a lot of submodules and I only want to get submodules from boost that is necessary to boost.filesystem

But When I use boost as submodule in my project and try to include the boost directory in cmake file, this error happen:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_subdirectory):
 The source directory
/home/lais/testeBoost/lib/boost
does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.
```

Comment: `ExternalProject_add` can deal with custom _configure_ and _build_ and _install_ commands. Just define the _configure_ to use the `bootstrap` command (to build b2) and _build_ command to use the `b2` command. AFAIK you don't need any python for b2.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I think it wll be right. One more doubt: is possible to specify what submodule from boost I want to clone? Because I only will use filesystem.a (static-lib) and its a long time to clone everything, build and install.

Comment: Download source tarball, build the `bcp` tool, use `bcp` to extract filesystem and its dependencies and build and install only these using `bootstrap` and `b2`.

Comment: I edited my question.